# Azure web app FTP or storage explorere permission to spefic folder only

Tags: azure

it is possible to give FTP user can access only Content folder  on Azure webapp or else give access via azure Storage explore.

please help about it i just want to give permission to my client only for content folder via FTP or azure storage explorer so that he can only upload their content on Specific folder.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, no.  FTP is an ALL or Nothing scenario.

An option would be add a path mapping in the Configuration section and mount Azure Blob or Azure Files and create a Shared Access Signature to grant write permissions to your client.